# mySQL returns result even though the database is empty

Tags: php, mysql

This SQL query return result and then session save empty variable like `$_SESSION["fbid"] = $user->fbid;` and array would be `Array ( [fbid] => )`.

```
   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `fbid` = '$fbid'") or die(mysqli_error());
   if ($result) {
   $user = $result->fetch_object();
        ...
```

The main question is, why is it passing through `if ($result)` when there isn't any records in the database?

Comment: Because an _empty_ result is still a _valid_ result.

Comment: It returns false when query was unsuccessful. If it was successful but returned empty set, check num_rows property of returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying `if($result)`

This states that your if will always be true.

You need to say `if($result == 1)` for example.

You need to have $result equal, or not equal.

That is how an if statement works.  However, you are saying "if query" which wont work anyways, you need to say something like,

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $user = $result->fetch_object();
}
```

Comment: `if($result == ''1)` worked, thank you! > 0 will probably work as well, but i think I will leave it to 1 as I also want to limit query to 1.

Comment: your welcome.  you should also change your query to `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE fbid = '$fbid LIMIT 1'"`

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli->query` returns either **true**, or **false** or `mysqli_result` object.

Both **true** and `mysqli_result` object will pass `if($result)`, and `false` returned in **case of error**. Getting empty result is not an error.

If you need to check if your query returns empty result, use `$num_rows` property, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your test `if ($result)` will only fail if `mysqli_query()` fails, perhaps with a syntax error.

If you have a valid query your test will pass. This is true even if your valid query returns an empty set (Finding nothing *is* a valid result).

You need to check the result of the query to ensure your query actually succeeded, but this is different from checking whether it returned anything.

Try

```
$result = $mysqli->query("select...");
if ($result->num_rows) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns `FALSE` if a query fails. In this case, it did not fail - it was successfully executed, and returned zero rows.

If you want to check for an empty result set, check the return value of [`fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

```
$user = $result->fetch_object();
if ($user) {
   # do stuff...
```